# How to prove Linear Independence of the given set

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to prove the following statement without sucess:

Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}, \lambda \neq 0, V = \{v_1 , \dots, v_i, \dots, v_m \} \subseteq  \mathbb{R}^n$ where $m \leq n$ and V is a linearly independent set,
then $\{v_1 , \dots, \lambda v_i, \dots, v_m \}$ is also a linearly independent set.

Any tips or guidelines on how to approach this?

Comment: Have you tried showing that $\{v_1,\ldots,\lambda v_i,\ldots, v_m\}$ satisfies the definition of "linearly independent"? Hint: use the fact that $\{v_1,\ldots,v_i,\ldots,v_m\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: I guess a conceptual idea to get you started it that any nonzero constant multiplied by a vector is going to be on the span of the original vector, and since by definition of linear independence none of the vectors in $V$ can be on another vector’s span, scaling one vector $v_i$ on its span is not going to affect linear independence.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there exists scalars $a_1,\dots,a_i,\dots,a_m$ such that $a_1v_1+\dots+a_i(\lambda v_i)+\dots+a_mv_m=0$. Because scalar multiplication is associative, we have that $a_1v_1+\dots+(a_i\lambda)v_i+\dots+a_mv_m=0$. Given that the list $v_1,\dots,v_i,\dots,v_m$ is linearly independent and that $\lambda \ne 0$ we conclude that $a_1=\dots=a_i=\dots=a_m=0$ and thus the list $v_1,\dots,\lambda v_i,\dots,v_m$ is linearly independent.

Comment: You introduced an unnecessary contradiction here. Just delete the “not all zero” and proceed.

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

(1) Let us consider some $ v_n $ which was a linear combination of the other elements in the old Set (OS), excluding $ v_i $. Then this $ v_n $ is still a linear combination of the other elements in the new Set (NS), excluding $ v_i $ ,because these other elements did not change.

(2) Let us next consider some $ v_m $ which was a linear combination of the other elements in OS, including $ v_i $. Then this $ v_m $ is still a linear combination of the other elements in NS, including $ v_i $, except that the weight $ (c)v_i $ will now be $ (c/\lambda) \lambda v_i $.

$ v_m = (c)v_i+\cdots $
$ v_m = (c/\lambda) \lambda v_i+\cdots $
[[ this is Possible , only because $ \lambda $ is not $0$ ]]

Let us lastly consider $v_i$ itself.
Either (3A) It was not a combination of the other elements in OS, in which case , we do not have to check that in NS.
Or (3B) It was a combination of the other elements in OS $ \{v_1 , \dots, v_i, \dots, v_m \} - \{ v_i \} $.

$ v_i = \Sigma \cdots $

Then we can get $ \lambda v_i $ in terms of the other elements in NS $ \{v_1 , \dots, \lambda v_i, \dots, v_m \} - \{ \lambda v_i \} $.

$ \lambda v_i =  \lambda \Sigma \cdots $

We have shown the "the original Set is not linearly InDependent" makes "the new Set is not linearly InDependent"

OBSERVATIONS :

By changing $ \lambda $ to $ 1/\lambda $ & using the same arguments , we can show that "the new Set is not linearly InDependent" makes "the original Set is not linearly InDependent"
In other words, both are Equivalent.
Scaling some ( or even all ) of the Elements in the Set ( by Non-Zero $ \lambda $ ) will not change the "Invariant" about linearly Dependent or linearly InDependent.

[[ thanks to user "Ted Shifrin" & user "Seeker" who gave useful criticisms on my earlier attempt ! ]]

Comment: This is not valid as it stands. How do you know you can solve for $\lambda v_i$? A non-contradiction proof is far more efficient.

Comment: What is the meaning of linearly Dependent ? A row **can** be obtained in terms of the others. What is the meaning of linear InDependent ? A row **can not** be obtained in terms of the others. I assume "linearly Dependent" which means I can get the new row, which implies that the original was also "linearly Dependent" which is a contradiction. [[ Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence "a set of vectors is linearly dependent if and only if one of them is zero or a linear combination of the others" ]]

Comment: [[ Also check https://deepai.org/machine-learning-glossary-and-terms/linearly-independent-vectors "A set of vectors is called linearly independent if no vector in the set can be expressed as a linear combination of the other vectors in the set" ]] This is basic criteria of linear Dependent or linear InDependent & my argument is indeed valid @TedShifrin

Comment: What @TedShifrin is trying to say is that you don't know that the specific $\lambda v_i$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the other vectors. Consider the linearly dependent list $(1, 2), (5, 6), (2, 4)$. This is linearly dependent because $-2(1, 2)+0(5, 6)+1(2, 4)=(0, 0)$. But we cannot express the vector $(5, 6)$ as a linear combination of $(1, 2)$ and $(2, 4)$. The point being that you don't know that the specific vector $\lambda v_i$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the other vectors.

Comment: Also that definition of linear dependence that you give in your first comment is completely wrong as shows by my example above. The correct definition is as follows. "A list of vectors $v_1,\dots,v_n$ is said to be linearly dependent if there exist scalars $a_1,\dots,a_n$ not all zero such that $a_1v_1+\dots+a_nv_n=0$". Notice that the definition allows for some scalars to be zero. But not all the scalars can be zero. I would heavily suggest learning about definitions in math from a math textbook and not machine learning websites. Nothing against them, you would just learn things better!

Comment: With your Detailed Explanation , I got the Point now @Seeker ! Thank you , both !

Comment: With the clarification by Seeker , I got your catch in my Answer , @TedShifrin , I will try to rectify it. In case, it is not going to work out, Deletion will be better option.

Comment: @Prem I’m glad it helped!